# Custom patterns with snakemake's paramspace

Tags: snakemake

Is it possible to use a custom `wildcard_pattern` and `instance_patterns` with [`snakemake.utils.Paramspace`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/snakemake/utils.html#Paramspace)?

Example:

Say the `Paramspace` looks like this

```
import snakemake
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["default","2030"],
    ["default","2050"],
    ], columns=["scenario","year"])
paramspace = snakemake.utils.Paramspace(df)
```

Then the `wildcard_pattern` and `instance_pattern` look like this

```
print(paramsapce.wildcard_pattern)
# 'scenario~{scenario}/year~{year}'


print(list(paramspace.instance_patterns))
# ['scenario~default/year~2030', 'scenario~default/year~2050']
```

What I want to do is have both patterns without the name of the wildcard prepended, i.e. I would like it to look like this:

```
print(paramsapce.wildcard_pattern)
# '{scenario}/{year}'


print(list(paramspace.instance_patterns))
# ['default/2030', 'default/2050']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a public function, and the code formats based on position instead of name, so changing the pattern won't cut it.

I would recommend just writing your own helper function to format the pattern you want.  The code uses iterrows and row.items in it's format call.

```
pattern = '{scenario}/{year}'
instance_patterns = [
    pattern.format(**dict(i for i in row.items())) 
    for _, row in df.iterrows()]
```

You could also open an issue requesting a change to either suppress having the parameter name or provide a custom formatter.  Currently, you can change the param separator (default `~`).